# JTable change row Class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

As the title may suggest, I'm trying to figure out how to change the class of rows, but more specifically I'm trying to change the class of certain rows, not every row. All I can find is how to change the class of columns.

I just cannot seem to find how to adjust the class on specific rows. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any solution except to create a `CellRenderer` changing the display component depending on row...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle that's what I was thinking as well, but I've gone through the methods and can't seem to find how to change a class without changing the whole columns class.

Comment: Can you tell us why you would want the class of rows, and what the context is?

Comment: @TT. might seem basic and done before, but I'm trying to create my own calendar/planner/events application where you can add events in each date, and the way I've done it is have one row of cells be the date # and then the cell directly below to contain the events then the it repeats. I want to add a list of events, different colors, etc.

Comment: You would need to create a class that implements the [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface, and use that as your table model in the JTable. Since the TableModel interface only has methods to get/set values at certain cells, you are free in your choice of data container and thus free to have a row represented by any class you want/need.

Comment: @TT. I don't know how I missed it, but I set my values as (String) so whenever I would try and add a value that wasnt a string it would give me an error message. I just set it to an Object array, so that I don't run into anymore trouble. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd approach it:

```
public class TableRenderer {
    interface ComponentTextSetter<T> {
        void setText(String value, T component);
    }
    private static final Map<Component, ComponentTextSetter> components = new HashMap() {
        {
            put(new JLabel(), (ComponentTextSetter<JLabel>) (value, component) -> component.setText(value));
            put(new JTextField(),
                    (ComponentTextSetter<JTextField>) (value, component) -> component.setText(value));
            put(new JComboBox<>(), (ComponentTextSetter<JComboBox>) (value, component) -> {
                component.addItem(value);
                component.setSelectedItem(value);
            });
        }
    };

    private static TableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component jComponent = new ArrayList<>(components.keySet()).get(row % components.size());
            components.get(jComponent).setText(value.toString(), jComponent);
            return jComponent;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(10, 3) {
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
                return "value" + new Random().nextInt(4);
            }
        };
        JTable jTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        jTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: renderer isn't right place to set, modify, change a models value, just the model is designated for

Comment: @mKorbel at which line exactly does my renderer change the value?